# Is it possible to get BundleID and Bundle name any compiled IOS app or android App?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am trying to secure my app for iOS and Android that I have built using PhoneGap. If anyone happens to break the app and get access to the Web Services URLs in the JS files, I would not want the Web Services to respond if they are called from a browser or from other app apart from mine.

The ways that I can think of are -
 1. Using User Agents to check where the requests are from. - It needs to be from device (BUT THE USER AGENTS CAN BE SPOOFED)
 2. Send the BundleID and Bundle Name to the WS for authentication. But my concern is if the app is broke can this information be accessed ?
3. Please recommend if there are other ways to protect the Web Services being used in, apart from the app it is intended to be used in.

Regards,
CM

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about security, use HTTPS.

Anything else can be easily spoofed from a computer.

Comment: Hello minipif, can you please help me understand how will HTTPS help as the WS URLs will be in the JS file ?

Comment: As Mike Weller commented, string constants are stored in plain text in your application, so they will be visible after decompilation. You can obfuscate them by calling a function that will somehow recreate your WS's URLs at runtime. It will make it harder to find, but not impossible (but nothing can, so...). Also, in Android, use [ProGuard](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) to hide your methods names.

Answer (score 0):

The bundle ID can be trivially extracted from iOS apps. An iOS .ipa is just a zip file with the .app inside it. The bundle ID can be found in the Info.plist file, as well as the code signing entitlements which can be read with the `codesign` tool.

You cannot really protect your web service from being used by non-app code. You could embed some kind of private key in the app and verify this on the server, but keys can always be extracted. It just depends on how much time you and potential attackers are willing to spend on the problem.

Comment: Hello Mike, Thanks for your response. Can an native app also be decompiled and the URL be extracted ?

Comment: If the URL is a simple string in the application, i.e. a `@"..."` constant, yes. Even if you try to obfuscate this, if somebody has enough time they can still figure it out. You can't 100% prevent non-app code from interacting with the web service.